# How to map function keys to compile my program?

Tags: vim

In VIM i want to map say function key Fn for compiling the currently open C/C++ file. Is that possible ? If yes please guide me.

Answer (score 5):

It is certainly possible and is my preferred way of working.

I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap    <F5>   :make<CR>
```

This will call `'makeprg'`, which defaults to `'make'`. Then you can use the results in Vim's [Quickfix](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#Quickfix) mode to tackle compilations errors, warnings, *etcetera*, which ([with the correct setup](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#compiler-select)) will deliver your cursor right to where the error lies in your code.

If you just want to compile the current file, you could set `'makeprg'` to something other than `'make`', such as your compiler, followed by the current file:

```
:set makeprg=g++\ %
```

[but then you'll need to add compiler flags such as include paths, etc.]

If you're using an alternative build system, such as [Boost Build](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/), [SCons](http://www.scons.org/), *et cetera*, then I humbly recommend using [**`Makeshift`**](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4278) to set `'makeprg'` for you.

Help topics in Vim to get you underway:

- [`:help :make`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3amake)
- [`:help :nnoremap`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#%3annoremap)
- [`:help :set`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%3aset)
- [`:help 'makeprg'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27makeprg%27)
- [`:help :_%`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a_%)

Comment: `<C-U>` is not necessary with nnoremap. It could be with x*map and v*map but in normal mode, : starts an empty command without range.

Comment: See also http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#compiler-select for some pre-configured compiler commands (and error parsers) which make it easy to use the quickfix list with things other than ``make``+``gcc`` .

Comment: Thanks David. Added your link to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible. Do you have a Makefile? Then insert this into your vimrc:

```
nnoremap <f1> :make<return>
```

This remaps the F1 key to invoke the internal command “make” of vim, which if you're running on a Linux machine will call gnu Make.

For more help, run `:help :make` and `:help :nnoremap`

Answer (score 2):

Fully subscribing the [Johnsyweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78845/johnsyweb)'s answer, I would also recommend to take a look at [SingleCompile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) plugin.  If it's sufficient for you to quickly compile *single-file* program, this plugin could just suit your needs.